# Regular expression to reject all non-English characters except some characters with accents

Tags: javascript, regex, non-english

This works great to disallow all non-English letters:

```
/[^\x00-\x7F]+/
```

But I *would* like to allow these characters:

```
âäèéêëîïôœùûüÿçÀÂÄÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸÇ
```

How do I add those to the regex so that they are allowed?

Comment: Yes, the original set of Unicode characters (C0 and  Basic Latin block) you cite includes the letters of the English alphabet but is insufficient for English text. Perhaps you should include ê and ﬀ, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the pattern like `/[^\x00-\x7F]+/` works for you, it matches all the letters you now want to avoid matching.

Since the `[^...]` is a [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), the easiest way to *exclude* a char/set of chars is to just add them to the class:

```
/[^\x00-\x7FâäèéêëîïôœùûüÿçÀÂÄÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸÇ]+/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bgvBdc/2).

If you use an empty string as the replacement pattern, you will remove every 1+ chars that are not ASCII (`\x00-\x7F`) and that are not equal to the letters added to the negated character class.

Comment: Thanks! To get it to work in Javascript, I had to find an online converter and use: /[^\x00-\x7F\u00E2\u00E4\u00E8\u00E9\u00EA\u00EB\u00EE\u00EF\u00F4\u0153\u00F9\u00FB\u00FC\u00FF\u00E7\u00C0\u00C2\u00C4\u00C8\u00C9\u00CA\u00CB\u00CE\u00CF\u00D4\u0152\u00D9\u00DB\u00DC\u0178\u00C7]+/

Comment: You actually do not need to do that. But [this is the converter I am using all the time](https://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/).

Answer (score 1):

Though it looks long one but a simple character class would do the job.

**Regex:** `[a-zA-ZâäèéêëîïôœùûüÿçÀÂÄÈÉÊËÎÏÔŒÙÛÜŸÇ]`